# Filter Array by keyword

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to write a search function for a data table, I have a collection of array objects and would prefer to search the whole object but right now I'm searching certain keys. The below code doesn't seem to work correctly.

I have tried the following js:

```
searchResults() {

   if (!this.searchTable) this.fetch_bet_data();

   const searchableKeys = ["username", "bet_id"];

   this.bets = this.bets.filter(bet => {

      return searchableKeys.some(key => {

         return bet[key].toLowerCase().includes(this.searchTable);

      });

   });

},
```

So it works via the `Bet_ID` but the username. It gets keyword from a search box

```
<input type="text" v-model="searchTable" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
   <div class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-success" @click="searchResults()" type="submit">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
      </button>
   </div>
```

Ideal world I'd like to just search the whole object, but right now just having it work on what i have declared would be great

Example of object:

```
bet_amount: "0.0000001" 
bet_id: "fe5f40-3ea93b" 
client_seed: "hash" 
created_at: 1547739644 
high: false 
multiplier: "2.00" 
nonce: 119
 profit: "-0.0000001" 
result: 
false roll: 80.82 
server_seed: "Seed is active needs to change server seed to reveal." server_seed_hash: "hash" 
threshold: 49.5 
user_id: "id" 
username: "graham"
```

Comment: what is `this.searchTable`? and `string`?

Comment: can you give us an example of `bet`?

Comment: Added to the main question

Answer (score 0):

One problem I can see with your approach.

You assign the filtered results to `this.bets` which means it will keep filtering on previous filters. You should assign the filtered result to a new variable.

Here is a working example.

```js
let bets = [
  {
    bet_amount: "0.0000001",
    bet_id: "fe5f40-3ea93b",
    client_seed: "hash",
    username: "graham"
  },
  {
    bet_amount: "0.0000002",
    bet_id: "kjs93f-sflll0",
    client_seed: "hash",
    username: "roller"
  },
  {
    bet_amount: "0.0000003",
    bet_id: "099s99-lpap11",
    client_seed: "hash",
    username: "card"
  }
]

function searchResults() {
  //if (!this.searchTable) this.fetch_bet_data();

  const searchableKeys = ["username", "bet_id"];

  let results = bets.filter(bet => {
    return searchableKeys.some(key => {
      return bet[key].toLowerCase().includes(document.getElementById("theInput").value);
    });
  });
  console.log(results);
}
```

```html
<input id="theInput" type="text" v-model="searchTable" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
<div class="input-group-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-success" onClick="searchResults()" type="submit">
         <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search">Search</i>
      </button>
</div>
```